# Change the background color on a custom Button?

Tags: java, swing

I want my button to change color on the mod == 0 of i % 3. The paintComponent(...) is called when the form is re-sized and index is passed in so I would think that this should change the color of my button ever time I start moving the form around the screen.

I have two components on the screen but both will not show up this might be a factor.

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class testform {
    public static void main (String[] p) {
         testBall3 j1  = new testBall3();
         myButton  b1  = new myButton("test");


         JPanel testPane = new JPanel();
         testPane.setBackground(Color.green);
         testPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         j1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,10));
         //testPane.add(b1);
         testPane.add(j1);

         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         frame.add(testPane);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setSize(300, 200); 
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setVisible(true);

         //j1.setColorBall(Color.BLACK);
         //j1.repaint();
    }
}

    class myButton extends JButton {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public myButton(String s) {
        super(s);   
    }

    public void setPrefferedSize(Dimension d) {
        //this.setBounds(x, y, width, height)
        setPreferredSize(d);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        index += i;
        System.out.println(i);
        if (index % 3 == 0) {
          setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        else {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
}

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

class testBall3 extends JComponent
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Color colorBall = Color.red;
    private int x1, y1;
    int index = 0;

    public void setColorBall(Color c)
    {
        this.colorBall = c;
    }

    public testBall3() 
    { 
        super();
        System.out.println("MyBall (0)");
    }

    public testBall3(int x, int y, int diameter)
    {
        super();
        this.setLocation(x, y);
        this.setSize(diameter, diameter);
        System.out.println("MyBall (1)");
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;
    }

    public void paintBorder(Graphics g) 
    {
         super.paintBorder(g);
         g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
         g.fillOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
         System.out.println("PaintBorder");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(colorBall);
        g.fillOval(x1, y1, 10, 10);
        System.out.println("paintComponent");
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paint(g);
        paintComponent(g);
        paintBorder(g);
        paintChildren(g);
        System.out.println("Paint");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

But [paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) doesn't take a second parameter, how are you passing it?  I would think that instead of trying to pass `i`, you would want make `i` an attribute of class myButton instead and initialize it to 0 upon instantiation.  That is, if you want each button to have its own counter.  That sounds like the better plan.

Comment: I changed that in my example. that way each button will have there own. But it still does not work the way that I was thinking that it should.

Comment: I see `i += i;`.  Is that a typo or is that in your real code?

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lot of strange stuff going on...

- You've got a component where you override all four major painting methods for no good reason.
- In this component, your paint method override calls the super method, and calls the other 3 methods, which in essence will make those 3 methods be called twice.
- You've got program logic (advancement of `i`) inside of your myButton's paintComponent method -- something that should never be done. You do not have full control over when or even if this method is called.
- You are calling `setBackground(...)` from within paintComponent, something which shouldn't be done.
- Your class names do not begin with an upper case letter, going against coding conventions, and potentially confusing anyone who tries to read your code.
- If you want to change the state of a component on resize, use a ComponentListener.

---

e.g.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Foo2 extends JPanel {
   protected static final Color MAGIC_BACKGROUND = Color.red;
   protected static final int MAGIC_NUMBER = 3;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;
   private int index = 0;
   private JButton myButton = new JButton("My Button");
   protected int DELTA_SIZE = 2;

   public Foo2() {
      add(myButton);
      addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

         @Override
         public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            index++;
            if (index % MAGIC_NUMBER == 0) {
               myButton.setBackground(MAGIC_BACKGROUND);
            } else {
               myButton.setBackground(null);
            }
         }

      });

      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
         private Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
         private int screenWidth = toolkit.getScreenSize().width;
         private int screenHeight = toolkit.getScreenSize().height;

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (getWidth() >= screenWidth || getHeight() >= screenHeight) {
               ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
            } else {
               int width = getWidth() + DELTA_SIZE;
               int height = getHeight() + DELTA_SIZE;
               setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
               Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Foo2.this);
               win.pack();
               win.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
         }
      }).start();
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new Foo2());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: This is more for testing an learning as opposed to how it should be done in the real world. I want to see all parts and pieces of how the paint works. I know that each JComponent has a Paint() which will call Update().

Comment: @DougHauf: but why have those methods called twice? Makes no sense. And what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @DougHauf: see edit to answer that shows how to change a JButton's background on GUI resize.